# How to change PDF title in new tab, or at least how to hide PDF file URL shown as title?

Tags: javascript, html

Like i said in question.

**How to change PDF title in new tab, or at least how to hide PDF file URL shown as title?**

I hope you guys can help me.

Regards,

Milan.

Comment: Yes, question is similar, but if you set PDF title metadata it will work in Mozilla only, but not in Chrome. How can i simply change that, why is so difficult?? I don't understand...

Comment: I assume because the browser loads up an adobe reader, which is an app which has its own settings and etc. I noticed that if you inspect a pdf on the web is had a title attribute in the head. Maybe you can change that? I don't know how you would.. because I don't think you can load your own scripts for that page.

Comment: Yes, you can, but it's only a PDF file name..i want to hide PDF file URL in title when new tab is opened...